# Writing productFlavor value to a file with Gradle task

Tags: android, gradle

I am setting up an Android project to support white labeling. As part of this setup, I need to write branding information (primary color etc.) to a file. To integrate this into the build process, I am trying to write a Gradle task to do this automatically. In the `app.gradle` file, I am specifying product flavors and specific values for each:

```
productFlavors {
    flavorA {
        dimension 'default'
        applicationId "com.myapp.flavora"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Flavor A"
        resValue "string", "primary_color", "#363636"
    }

    ...
}
```

I then have a Gradle task to write to the file:

```
task copyGlobals {
    println "COPY GLOBALS"
    project.file('../globals.js') << 'hello world'
}
```

My question is: How can I load the `primary_color` value and write it to the `globals.js` file within the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the product flavors, you need to iterate all applicationVariants:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant variant ->
    // Here you can check concrete flavor, for example:
    if (variant.flavorName == "flavorA") {
        // Here you need to iterate all resValues of your variant
        variant.mergedFlavor.resValues.each { String key, com.android.builder.model.ClassField field ->
            // field.name - is name of your resValue, for example, "primary_color"
            // field.value - is value of your resValue, for example, "#363636"
            println "Name = ${field.name}  Value = ${field.value}"
            // Also you can get your value through  String key.
            println "Value = $key"
        }
    }
}
```